# Multiple file stream instead of download to disk and then zip?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I have an API method that when called and passed an array of file keys, downloads them from S3. I'd like to stream them, rather than download to disk, followed by zipping the files and returning that to the client.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
reports.get('/xxx/:filenames ', async (req, res) => {

  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();

  var str_array = filenames.split(','); 

  for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {

  var filename = str_array[i].trim();
  localFileName = './' + filename;

  var params = { 
    Bucket: config.reportBucket,
    Key: filename
  }

      s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {

        if (err) console.error(err)
        var file = require('fs').createWriteStream(localFileName);
        s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
        console.log(file);
    })
  }
});
```

How would I stream the files rather than downloading them to disk and how would I zip them to return that to the client?

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is to zip multiple files. 
More specifically, download them from AWS S3 in bulk.
I've searched through [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) and didn't find bulk s3 operations.
Which brings us to one possible solution:

1. Load files one by one and store them to folder
2. Zip folder (with some package like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-folder))
3. Send zipped folder

This is raw and untested example, but it might give you the idea:

```
// Always import packages at the beginning of the file.
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const zipFolder = require('zip-folder');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

reports.get('/xxx/:filenames ', async (req, res) => {

   const filesArray = filenames.split(','); 

   for (const fileName of filesArray) {
     const localFileName = './' + filename.trim();

     const params = { 
       Bucket: config.reportBucket,
       Key: filename
     }

     // Probably you'll need here some Promise logic, to handle stream operation end. 
     const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(localFileName);
     s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(fileStream);
   }

   // After that all required files would be in some target folder.
   // Now you need to compress the folder and send it back to user.

   // We cover callback function in promise, to make code looks "sync" way.
   await new Promise(resolve => zipFolder('/path/to/the/folder', '/path/to/archive.zip', (err) => {resolve()}); 

   // And now you can send zipped folder to user (also using streams).
   fs.createReadStream('/path/to/archive.zip').pipe(res);
 });
```

Info about streams [link](https://www.dev2qa.com/node-js-stream-example/) and [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93)

**Attention:** You'll probably could have some problems with async behaviour, according to streams nature, so, please, first of all, check if all files are stored in folder before zipping.

Just a mention, I've not tested this code. So if any questions appear, let's debug together